# Is it possible to synchronize dygraphs with other charts using same timestamps?

Tags: synchronization, dygraphs

For example my raw data has the following columns: `[timestamps, speed, latitude, longitutde]` and I use dygraphs to generate a `speed` over `timestamps` chart. Somehow on the same page I'd like to generate the geographic track using the `latitude` & `longtitude` coordinates with another charting lib (not sure exactly which one yet).

Is it then possible to make the two charts synchronized? If so, how?

The expectation is when the mouse hover on a certain `speed` data point, the corresponding `timestamp` is returned and can be used in some mechanism to mark the corresponding location point on the whole geographic track. And vice versa.

FWIW, `timestamps` have unique values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. You want to specify the [`highlightCallback`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#highlightCallback) and `unhighlightCallback` options. They get called when the user mouses over the chart and then mouses off it. Check out [this demo](http://dygraphs.com/tests/callback.html) to see when they fire. The second parameter to the `highlightCallback` function is your timestamp.

Comment: thanks for the hint. I've managed to set up the interaction from my dygraphs chart to a map chart. Now, on the "reversed" direction, do I use the `setSelection` method to set the highlight point?